# SSIS: Create Folder & Archive File in one task

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have SSIS packages, which load some data and finally archive the files in certain folders.

[image]

"Create Archive Folder if not exists" 
Will just do a simple `Operation "Create Directory"` with `OverwriteDestinationFile=True`

"Archive InputFile"
will do an `Operation "RenameFile"`
basically just changing the filepath from the load directory to the archive directory

I am just using the first task to gurantee the destination directory exists before moving/renaming the file.

Can't i do those two tasks in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, its possible. You ll need to script it.

Create 2 variables. Source path and destination path.

Namespace : `using System.IO;`

```
    string fileName = "test.txt"; //file name
    string sourcePath = Dts.Variables["User::var_source"].Value.ToString(); //source path
    string targetPath = Dts.Variables["User::var_destination"].Value.ToString(); //destination path with folder

    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

screenshot :

[image: img]

Comment: thx - i will try to to id like you said, when i have some time. currently struggling with some other problems at work^^

Comment: Yep sure. Tag me incase you get stuck. :)